# Dark themed application with light dialogs

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a dark theme for my android app but with light dialogs. So far this has been a nightmare trying to figure out.

Basically, my dark theme style looks like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/darkPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/darkPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/darkPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/transparentWhite</item>
</style>
```

Everything looks good except the AlertDialogs. The AlertDialogs are white (as they should be), but the widgets (TextViews, EditTexts, etc.) I have inside my AlertDialogs are also white. I assume the AlertDialogs are using the `android:textColorPrimary` style of my theme. So how can I specify a different `android:textColorPrimary` only for AlertDialogs?

I tried adding the following style to my theme:

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
```

And then another style:

```
<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

But it has no effect. I've tried a multitudde of other things such as setting styles `android:textAppearance`, `android:textViewStyle`. I can't get anything to work. There must be some simple way to apply the light theme only to dialogs with black text as the primary text, while maintaining white primary text in the application.

**Edit:** So I finally got things working how I want, and I'll post the solution in case anyone else comes across the same problems. I used the ContextThemeWrapper like @Jeffrey suggested, but with R.style.ThemeOverlay_AppCompat_Light.
However, for some reason, this didn't seem to work for one dialog that I had a custom view and had EditTexts. The EditTexts weren't being styled for whatever reason, so I had to apply the theme to the root attribute in the custom view's layout xml:

```
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

Comment: Your dialog theme is using a different parent - in the specification - do both of those parents point to the same place?

Comment: You mean to remove the "Base." from the AlertDialogTheme parent? Tried it, it didn't help.

Comment: That's what I meant. Thank you. Sorry it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try passing the theme in a `ContextThemeWrapper`?

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
  new AlertDialog.Builder(
    new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AlertDialogTheme));
```

Here's the layout for alert dialogs:

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml

You can see the message text view uses `style="android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`. Have you tried redefining this in your dialog style? E.g.,

```
<item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/MyTextAppearanc‌​e.Medium</item>
```

Comment: Yes I've tried this and I also tried passing R.style.AlertDialogTheme as the second argument to a couple of AlertDialogs and nothing is working. The text colors in the dialogs are only coming from the AppTheme.Dark's `android:textColorPrimary` and `android:textColorSecondary`. Am I misunderstanding how styling works? Do I need to style each TextView/EditText within the dialog individually?

Comment: Here's the layout for alert dialogs: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog.xml. You can see the `message` text view uses `style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"`. Have you tried redefining this in your dialog style? E.g., `<item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/OobeTextAppearance.Medium</item>`